# Reactable: Conditional styling in groups

Tags: r, reactable

I'm trying to combine the following two [reactable](https://glin.github.io/reactable/) features in R:

- Conditional styling
- Aggregating / grouping

My goal is to highlight the aggregated (sum) group headers with different shades of orange, depending on the group sum value. This way, it's easier to spot groups with high/low values.

I use only one color range `c("#ffe4cc", "#ffb54d")` for both cell values and group headers, e.g. `100` as cell value and `100` as group header result in the same color.

---

What I've tried so far (this is a simplified example, my real world problem needs highlighting over multiple columns/groups):

```
library(datasets)
library(reactable)

data('CO2')

get_orange <- function(x) rgb(colorRamp(c("#ffe4cc", "#ffb54d"))(x), maxColorValue = 255)

reactable(
  CO2,
  groupBy = c('Plant', 'Type', 'Treatment'),
  columns = list(
    conc = colDef(
      aggregate = 'mean'
    ),
    uptake = colDef(
      aggregate = 'sum',
      style = function(value) {
        normalized <- (value - min(CO2$uptake)) / (max(CO2$uptake) - min(CO2$uptake))
        color <- get_orange(normalized)
        list(background = color)
      }
    )
  )
)
```

Resulting in:
[Screenshot expected vs actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npdvi.png)

---

```
> packageVersion('reactable')
[1] ‘0.2.3’
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for the conditional styling in groups.

By injecting a JS function in [colDef(style=)](https://glin.github.io/reactable/reference/colDef.html) of reactable, the color of each cell can be calculated.

You can find the full example [here](https://gist.github.com/fbardos/fdeba63b5752ed39e86229404d48b4d5).

For each column you want with a conditional format, you have to bypass a `JS()` function, like so:

```
for (column in dynamic_cols){
    script = paste("
      // source: https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html#grouped-cell-rendering-1
      function(rowInfo) {
        // source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44134328/4856719
        function hslToHex(h, s, l) {
          l /= 100;
          const a = s * Math.min(l, 1 - l) / 100;
          const f = n => {
        const k = (n + h / 30) % 12;
        const color = l - a * Math.max(Math.min(k - 3, 9 - k, 1), -1);
        return Math.round(255 * color).toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
          };
          return `#${f(0)}${f(8)}${f(4)}`;
        }
        var value = rowInfo.row['", column, "']
        var max = ", q, "
        var min = 0
        // pct_value = (value - min) * 100 / (max - min)
        pct_value = (Math.min(value, max) - min) * 100 / (max - min)
        // If value equals 0, set font color grey.
        if (value == 0) {
          var color = '#adafaa'
          var bg = '#fff'
        } else {
          var color = '#000000'
          var bg = hslToHex(40, pct_value, 95 - pct_value / 2)
        }
        return { color: color, backgroundColor: bg}
    }", sep="")

    dynamic_col_def[column] <- list(colDef(
      aggregate = 'sum', style = JS(script)
    ))
}
```

The injected JS function does consume `rowInfo` as input parameter and returns a named list. In this case, we return text color `color` and cell background color `backgroundColor`.

With this workaround, you can either set a custom color range for each column in the table or combine multiple columns to one color range.

The thread on `github/glin/reactable` can be found [here](https://github.com/glin/reactable/issues/200#issuecomment-951063029).